# print array keys which has some values

Tags: php

I have an array

```
Array(
       'Name'=> 'ashish',
       'Course'=>'btech',
       'Branch'=> 
);
```

Is there a predefined function in PHP which can give me this output:

name, course

Comment: give more information. What is the structure of input ?

Comment: Hi Ashish rawat, and welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions here are expected to show research effort, that is, what you've already done to solve your problem. We're happy to help, but only after you've tried yourself. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Good luck!

Comment: This array has an invalid syntax.. it would be impossible to get this output

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `array_filter()` to strip out all empty values and then use `array_keys()` to get just the keys:

```
$keyList = array_keys(array_filter($array, 'strlen'));
```

Now you can print out the result you wanted by running the array through `array_map()` again to get the lowercase results and then `implode()` to print it with commas between parameters:

```
echo implode(', ', array_map('strtolower', $keyList));
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use array_keys() function with array_map and strtolower

```
$array = array_keys(['Name' => 'ashish',
    'Course' => 'btech',
    'Branch' => 'test']);
echo implode(', ', array_map('strtolower', $array));
```

Comment: array_key($arr); will print the branch key as well. But i want only those keys which has some values

Comment: can you try this one ?